# Ping time = 0 with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Here is my code to measure ping time based on boost asio :

```
void PingServiceImpl::pingHost(  const std::string& remoteIp,
                                 const PingService::TimeDuration& timeout )
{
   sendRequestTo(remoteIp, timeout);
   receiveResponseFrom(remoteIp);
}

void PingServiceImpl::sendRequestTo(const std::string& remoteIp, const TimeDuration& timeout)
{
   boost::asio::ip::icmp::resolver remoteEndpointResolver(m_ioService);
   boost::asio::ip::icmp::endpoint remoteEndpoint = *remoteEndpointResolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::icmp::resolver::query(boost::asio::ip::icmp::v4(), remoteIp.c_str(), ""));

   std::string body = "icmp request to " + remoteIp;

   IcmpHeader echoRequest;
   echoRequest.type(IcmpHeader::echo_request);
   echoRequest.code(0);
   echoRequest.identifier(getProcId());
   echoRequest.sequence_number(++m_sequenceNumber);

   boost::uint16_t checksum = compute_checksum( echoRequest,
                                                body.begin(),
                                                body.end());
   echoRequest.checksum(checksum);

   boost::asio::streambuf requestBuffer;
   std::ostream outStream(&requestBuffer);
   outStream << echoRequest << body;

   m_timeBeforeRequestSend = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

   m_socket.send_to(requestBuffer.data(), remoteEndpoint);

   m_timer.expires_at(m_timeBeforeRequestSend + timeout);
   m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&PingServiceImpl::handleTimeout, this));
}

void PingServiceImpl::receiveResponseFrom(const std::string& remoteIp)
{
   m_replyBuffer.consume(m_replyBuffer.size());
   m_socket.async_receive(m_replyBuffer.prepare(65536),
                         boost::bind(&PingServiceImpl::handleReceiveResponse, this, _1, remoteIp, _2));
}

void PingServiceImpl::handleReceiveResponse( const boost::system::error_code& error,
                                             std::string remoteIp,
                                             std::size_t responseSize)
{
   if(!error)
   {
      m_replyBuffer.commit(responseSize);

      std::istream inputStream(&m_replyBuffer);
      ipv4_header ipv4Header;
      IcmpHeader icmpHeader;

      inputStream >> ipv4Header >> icmpHeader;

      std::string expectedBody = "icmp request to " + remoteIp;

      if (icmpHeader.type() == IcmpHeader::echo_reply
      && icmpHeader.identifier() == getProcId()
      && icmpHeader.sequence_number() == m_sequenceNumber
      && icmpHeader.checksum() == compute_checksum(icmpHeader, expectedBody.begin(), expectedBody.end()))
      {
         m_timer.cancel();
         m_timeAfterResponseReceive = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();

         boost::system::error_code ec = boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::success);
         this->m_pingHandler( m_timeAfterResponseReceive - m_timeBeforeRequestSend, ec );
      }
   }
}
```

m_timeAfterResponseReceive - is the current time when RX message is obtained
m_timeBeforeRequestSend - is the current time when TX happened

With this I get ping time = 0. How that could be? Even Windows cmd ping utility gives 1 ms for localhost. What am I doing wrong ?

BR,
Dmitry

Comment: Are you pinging your local host?  Windows reports `<1ms` for local host pings for me.

Comment: No, some PC from my net. I get about 2 ms from ping...

Comment: And I would expect some microsec results cuz I use microsec_clock resolution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12972623/85371

Comment: Thanks - that is a good explanation for the observation I have